# Trouble getting FORM submitted to Mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, forms

I have one page which has one input text box and that data needs to be either inserted or updating the existing row.

I will echo it later, that is under control.

```
<form method="post" name="tapahtuma">
Submit: 
<input type="text" name="auts[]"> 
<input type="button" value="Ilmoita">
</form >

<?php

if(isset( $_POST["tapahtuma"]) ) {
$link = mysql_connect("localhost","root","","db");
mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO table (column) VALUES ('".$auts."')");
$auts = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['auts']);
mysqli_close($link);
}

?>
```

Comment: Where is `submit` button?

Comment: change type from `button` to `submit`

Comment: Lots of flaws are there in your given code. You need to understand basic php coding first.

Comment: You are mixing `mysql` and `mysqli`

Comment: Your syntax is highly questionable..  Also you should have an undefined variable $auts

Comment: Move `$auts = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['auts']);` above your mysqli_query.

Comment: I know that this is not the best available coding here, but in all fairness, I've tried lot of variations, but doesn't seem to go anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

According to the code provided.

**Changes**

1. Change `<input type="button" value="Ilmoita">` to `<input type="submit"  name="Ilmoita" value="Ilmoita">`
2. Change `if(isset( $_POST["tapahtuma"]) ) {` to `if(isset( $_POST["Ilmoita"]) ) {`
3. Change `$link = mysql_connect("localhost","root","","db");` to `$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db");`
4. Put `$auts = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['auts']);` before `mysqli_query`

**Updated Code**

```
<form method="post" name="tapahtuma">
  <input type="text" name="auts">
  Submit: <input type="submit" name="Ilmoita" value="Ilmoita">
</form >
<?php

if(isset( $_POST["Ilmoita"]) ) {
  $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db");
  $auts = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['auts']);
  mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO table (column) VALUES ('".$auts."')");
  mysqli_close($link);
}?>
```

I will suggest you to use [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) to avoid [SQL Injections](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp)

```
<form method="post" name="tapahtuma">
  <input type="text" name="auts">
  Submit: <input type="submit" name="Ilmoita" value="Ilmoita">
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST["Ilmoita"])) {
  $link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db") or die("connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
  $result = mysqli_prepare($link, "INSERT INTO `table` (`column`) VALUES (?)");
  mysqli_stmt_bind_param($result, "s", $_POST['auts']);
  mysqli_stmt_execute($result);
  mysqli_close($link);
}?>
```

**Quick Links**

- [mysqli_prepare](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)
- [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: It's on localhost so not worried about sqli

Comment: This isn't updating my mysql db either. The connection should be alright, but cannot get it to post anything tho' Database is set to varchar. Should it be something else?

Comment: Then, it's your DB Connection problem. Check whether DB Credentials are properly passed in database connection method @Miggs

Comment: I've updated my answer. I forgotten to add `name="Ilmoita"` in submit button. Have a look and try again @Miggs

Comment: Hello, so if I update a date table with this function, it works like a charm. Text doesn't so I really do not know what it is that could cause this.

Comment: Got it working without prepared statements, I will update shortly here

Answer (score 0):

```
<form method="post" name="tapahtuma">
Vapaa teksti: <input type="text" name="auts">
<input type="submit" value="ilmoita" name="ilmoita">
</form >

<?php

if(isset( $_POST["ilmoita"]) ) {
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","db");
$auts = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['auts']);
mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO table (column) VALUES ('$auts')");
mysqli_close($link);
}?>
```

What I did, is that I used mysql**i**_real_escape_string instead of mysql_real_escape_string and also added the $link there as well.

I will test with the prepared statements sometime, but at least this works and it really isn't a concern with the sqli exploits.